# Folder/path restriction in Windows XP

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-xp

`Batch file` created to delete folders older than N days.
**The file do the work excellent in some folders except a specific `path`,** So when I edit the batch file and set the path to the desired folder the batch file start executing and shows me the `echo` messages... then it looks like it freeze when start searching the desired `path` folders! The OS is WINDOWS XP. Is that mean that someone did access restriction to that `path` in windows? by the way - I can access to all folders in that `path` through Explorer and do delete/copy without any problem!! Any ideas to solve? Thanks.

Comment: does this path contain spaces?

Comment: NO. it is without any space!

Comment: then.How long are the paths? Do the exceed the command max length 8191?

Comment: I think it is Network issue... as @Musakkhir comment below.. I'll check it now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using C drive use another drive or use network path.

Comment: This is not C drive it is D drive!

Answer (score 0):

try to run as administrator as using this command.       runas /savecred /user:(domain)(admin user) "(file path to exe,bat,whatever)"

Comment: I run it from Command prompt and got this: RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - D:\myfolder\myfile.bat the service can't be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

Comment: In RUNAS USAGE: /savecred - to use credentials previously by user. This option is not available on Windows XP Home Edition and will be ignored.

Comment: Got the same error when using the switches: `/user program` and `/netonly`.